# Fatal error: Class 'Memcache'

Tags: cron, php, memcached

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in /var/www/***/data/www/***/***.php on line 47 Exited with return code = 255
```

Вот такие дела вижу при запуске крона через ispmanager :((( а так все нормально работает и Memcache летает. Подскажите как быть :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не было php.ini в том месте где нужно, а на сайте он брался с php-bin от сюда и беда :)

Answer (score 0):

А модуль `php-pecl-memcache` установлен?
И не забудьте передернуть `httpd` после установки.